# What is the best way to generate pdf or other file type like xls on php?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I usualy use fpdf to do that , but i feel confuse and not simple enough . is there any php framework except that .

Answer (score 0):

You can you yii Framework with tcpdf extention to generate pdf with tcpdf http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/tcpdf/

To generate xls you can use the phpexcel Yii extention http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpexcel/